# Multi-catches are not supported a this language level

Tags: java, exception, hashmap

So I want to type a number, and then a name of a person or something else. There is no problem with that, but why can't I put 2 error exceptions in 1 block?

```
while (true) {
    try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt( reader.readLine() );
        String name = reader.readLine();

        if (name.equals("")) {
            break;
        }

        map.put(name, id);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to print my value, I get `NumberFormatException`

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> pair: map.entrySet()) {
    int id = pair.getKey();
    String name = pair.getValue();
    System.out.println(id + " " + name);
}
```

Comment: The exception you're getting is not coming from the code snippet you put here. It's coming from some other part of your program.

Comment: its working now, but its deleting names if it contains same numbers, hmm.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is not in the code, but in the compiler level. Just check your IDE settings and set the compiler level to 1.7 or higher.

Comment: nah, its still not supporting =\

Comment: im using intellj IDEA, i changed compiler to 1.8

Comment: Try to open "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "Project settings" -> "Project" -> "Project language level" and set it to 7.0.

Comment: I have the same problem and i am using eclipse IDE  @Artyomcool can u guys help ?  I have already changed the compiler to 1.7 i.e. properties>javacompiler>1.7

Comment: @praveen same here, I'm using JDK 1.7 and IntelliJ is still complaining about a multi-catch.

Comment: @praveen nvm, just got it. Posted an answer if anyone finds this Q whil looking for a solution in a similar situation.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using IntelliJ and set it to 7.0 properly in the following path and still didn't work:

> File -> Project Structure -> Project settings -> Project -> Project language level

Set in the module:

> File -> Project Structure -> Project settings -> **Modules** -> **Project language level**

Comment: The IDE has no Project language level in Modules section. Edit: It was on the sources tab, thank you

Answer (score 6):

In my case, an explicit configuration in my `pom.xml` did the trick. The IntelliJ setting in *File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project language level* was set to my JDK 1.7 but the IDE kept ignoring the setting.

I used the Maven Compiler Plugin to specify the source and target version as 1.7

To do so, in the `<plugins>` section, add the following lines:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```